# HTML form with external php form processing?

Tags: php, forms

Below I have my html and php coding. I've racked my brain trying several different options, but what I am really looking for is something simple and secure that either reloads to my original page showing sent message. As of right now I get this error message when submitting my form. Someone please point me in the right direction, any feedback is appreciated.

HTML CODING(index.html)

```
<html>
  <head><title></title></head>
  <body>

    <div id="wrapper2">
      <div id="newsletter" class="container">
        <div class="title">

          <img src="images/port-formdivide.png" alt="" width="800" height="60" />

          <h2>Contact Me</h2>
          <span class="byline">Please complete the entire form.</span> </div>

        <div class="content">
          <form action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self">

            <div class="row half">
              <div class="6u">
                <input name="name/company" id="name/company" type="text" class="text" maxlength="30"
                       placeholder="Name/Company" value="" />
              </div>

              <div class="6u">
                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="text" maxlength="30"
                       placeholder="Email" value="" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row half">
              <div class="12u">
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" value=""></textarea>

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="12u">
                <input name="Send Message" type="submit" class="button submit" value="Send Message" />
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

PHP CODING(form.php)

```
<?php
// Email Variables
$to = 'inquiries@triston-thomas.com';
$subject = 'New Inquiry';

/* Data Variables */
if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "form"){

    $emailTitle = 'New Message Triston';
    $yourEmail = 'inquiries@triston-thomas.com':

    $name/company = $_POST['name/company'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    echo ("Name/Company:" . $name/company);
    echo ("<br />Email:" . $email);
    echo ("<br />Message:" . $message);

    function response($name/company);
    {
        echo ("Thank You " . $name/company);
    }

    header ("Location: index.html");

    mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: ".$name/company);
    echo "Your Inquiry Has Been Sent";

    // Set Required Fields
    $required_ fields = array("$name/company","$email","$message");

    // Set Error Messages
    $error_message = array("$name/company" => 'Please Enter Your Name or Company Name In
    The Field',

                           "$email" => 'Valid Email Address Is Required',
                           "$message" => 'Please Enter Message In The  Field',);


    /*Behaviors*/
    if ($_POST)
        {
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
        }

    if(isset($_POST['message']))
        {
            echo $_POST['name/company'];
            echo "<br />";
            echo $_POST['email'];
            echo "<br />";
            echo $_POST['message'];
        }

    if(empty($_POST['name/company']))
        {
            echo "Name Field is Required";
        }

    if(empty($_POST['email']))
        {
            echo "Email Field is Required";
        }

    if(empty($_POST['message']))
        {
            echo "Message Field is Required";
        }

    $body = <<<EOD
        <br><hr><br>
    Name/Company: $name/company <br />
        Email: $email <br />
        Message: $message <br />

        EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail("$yourEmail", "$emailTitle", "$body", "$headers");

    $sent = "Thank You, Your Inquiry Has Been Sent";

    echo $result;

    enter code here

        }

?>
```

Comment: `$name/company = $_POST['name/company'];` is not a valid assignment, because `$name/company` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Error Message is (Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.)